# integrate formio api with my angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, formio, angular-dragdrop

[Source code](https://github.com/formio/angular-formio)  in git

[Live Demo](https://formio.github.io/angular-demo/#/forms/builder)

I want to develop Angular8 drag and drop form builder functionality in my angular application
In the above git code it is developed using pure `formio`

My requirement is I want to integrate this angular drag and drop functionality in my already existing angular project.

I am struck to integrate `formio`, Please help me How can I strat the integration.

is there any tutorial available with explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to install formio in your project

```
npm install --save angular-formio
```

then import formioModule in your project module

```
import { FormioModule } from 'angular-formio';
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, CommonModule, FormioModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

after that if you want to build a form using formio then call `formio-builder` in your component and save form json in database by calling rest api.

```
<form-builder [form]="{
  components: []
}"></form-builder>
```

and if you want to show your form in component then use formion renderer

```
<formio src='https://examples.form.io/example'></formio>
```

let me know if you need any help.